# Assemble || onComplete

Tags: node.js, assemble

Is there something built into Assemble API to alert/emit/notify when the build() function is totally complete?

I have the piping working as it should but my next function is directly tied to the expected file being saved at it's destination.

--- An example of the code below ---

Assemble App in Class A:

```
//...

app.build('default' (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    this.complete();
})

// ...
```

Sibling Function in Call B:

```
// ...

foo () {
    assemble.app.on('complete', () => {
        // Error here, file not saved to destination yet.
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: will you add more specifics... like what is in your "default" task that `app.build` is running? There might be something in there that tell us if the task is ending before the file is written to the destination.

Comment: The app object is ruffly based on the assemble example at this link: https://github.com/assemble/assemble/blob/master/examples/blog/assemblefile.js

I can't seem to track down an onComplete emit from assemble. So far I've been able to build one myself, and it works. However, it seems to be throwing multiple times and causing a new and different error.

Comment: Got it. This actually seems to not be an issue with Assemble at all. In the end it's a timing issue and a set header within my Express engine. Assemble is doing what it's supposed to do but wasn't checking for set headers. After that, it's all about clearing out old headers, cleaning up emitter event listeners and unbinding old files. Thanks for taking the time @doowb.